# Docker compose force pull when build is specified

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is is possible to skip build step even if it's specified. For example for the following file only `redis` image is pulled after running `docker-compose pull` command.

```
version: '3.4'
   
services:

  myservice:
    image: ${PRIVATE_REGISTRY-}my-service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyService/Dockerfile
    ports: [5555:80]

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: ${RESTART_POLICY-no}
```

And if I remove `build:` step from the file then the other image is getting pulled as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, generally this is not possible as docker doesn't know then what to do. If you access the situation that your image doesn't have to be built everytime then try considering building it from cli when this is needed. In general I would advise to work with images and named versions. This version may be "lastest" for example in CI. Suggestion to take this approach:

- DEV: your approach is perfect for often changing containers
- STAGE: when moving from dev to stage, tag the images and give them a version. Only use namend versions in higher environments
- PROD: same as stage, other version naming strategies